# K means permute clusters

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

With the following code from a book I am clustering the digits dataset. Because the K means algorithm can find the clusters but has no knowledge about which cluster is for example a "0" or a "9" we must Match each learned cluster label with the true labels found in them.

```
digits=load_digits()
X=digits.data
y=digits.target

#Instantiate the k_means estimator and set the hyerparameters
model=KMeans(n_clusters=10,random_state=0)
model.fit(X)
y_pred=model.predict(X)

#Match each learned cluster label with the true labels found in them
from scipy.stats import mode

labels=np.zeros_like(y_pred)
for i in range(10):
    mask=(y_pred==i)
    labels[mask]=mode(digits.target[mask])[0]

conf=confusion_matrix(y,labels)
```

I understand all of the code except the part:

```
        labels[mask]=mode(digits.target[mask])[0]
```

Can anybody please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mode()` in statistics means the value that appears most often in a set. Thus, the "true" digit that matches cluster `mask` is the one appearing most frequent in all digits belonging to cluster `mask`.
So,

```
digits.target[mask] # the set of all true labels of cluster `mask`
```

Taking the [`mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html):

```
mode(digits.target[mask])  # finds the most frequent digit in this cluster
```

Assign it to `labels[mask]`, thus matching the k-means clusters and the true digits in the set:

```
labels[mask]=mode(digits.target[mask])[0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Means the "mask" array is like a "Pattern" which matches the "true" label from digits.target with the predicted label from y_pred. If y_pred predicts for instance the number 1 (maks == True if y_pred ==1), the "mask" array gets overlayed to the digits.target array and reveals for example the number 3. With that we know that each time y_pred predicts the number 1, this is the number/ digit 3. Following this procedure the "labels" array gets filled step by step with the "true" numbers at the corresponding positions